# Retrieving the proper file from a directory with ~280,000 files

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have ~280,000 files that will need to be searched through, and the proper file returned and opened.  The file names are exact matches of the expected search terms.

The search terms will be taken by an input box using PHP.  What is the best way to accomplish this so that searches do not take a large amount of time?

Thanks!

Comment: if the file names are exact matches to the search terms, why do you need to search through the files at all? Can't you just open the one matches exactly?

Comment: If the filename is exact match you don't need to search. You can just open it. Is there any reason you need to search for it?

Comment: Why is your question tagged `[mysql]`?

Comment: store the name of files in database using myISAM engine which enables full text search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the file system *itself* will struggle with 280,000 files in one directory.

An approach I've taken in the past is to put those files in subdirectories based upon the initial letters of the filename e.g.

```
1/100000.txt
1/100001.txt
...
9/900000.txt
```

etc. You can subdivide further using the second letter etc.

Comment: This is touching on the principles of a radix sort. Good answer.

Comment: A good file system can handle that many with ease unless you try to list them.

Comment: This still potentially leaves ~10,800 entries to iterate over if the search isn't case sesitive. That number probably low too considering that there wouldn't be many file starting with Z, Y, Q etc. I think caching the avialable filenames and location to a database would be wildly more efficent. Especially something like Mongo or Redis, where you can take advantage of memory rather than reading a physical drive for every search.

Comment: A common, closely related approach is to store files based on the hash of the filename -- for instance, `MD5(100000.txt)` = `9cf641060f189c8f215dcd0420d146c4`, so you'd store it as `9c/f6/100000.txt`. (Yes, MD5 is considered broken, but it's fine as a non-crypto hash, like here.)

Answer (score 0):

Its good you added mysql to your tags. Ideally i would have a CRON task that would index the directories into a mysql table and use that to do the actual search. Algebra is faster than File System iteration. You could run the task daily or hourly depending on how often your files change. Or use something like Guard to monitor the file system for changes and make appropriate updates.

See: https://github.com/guard/guard